# Extracting values from a col string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a col in pandas df of logs.

```
col
Sequential mode! HostOsCheck fails, so bye!
[c01][OK][HostOsCheck] Skip cji02  because it is DOWN
[c01][Stage 3] 2/3 checks passed
[c01][FAIL][HostOsCheck] Percentage working
[c01][FAIL][HostOsCheck] Percentage working
[c02][OK][ILOStatusCheck] Percentage of working
```

If the string has word [OK] it means the check passed and if it has [FAIL] it means the check failed.

I want to extract logs with the type of check(the name with Check), cluster name, and status (passed or failed) by creating separate cols for the same in df like below:

```
col cluster Status  name
Sequential mode! HostOsCheck fails, so bye! c01 NA  HostOsCheck
[c01][OK][HostOsCheck] Skip cji02  because it is DOWN   c01 OK  HostOsCheck
[c01][Stage 3] 2/3 checks passed    c01 NA  NA
[c01][FAIL][HostOsCheck] Percentage working c01 FAIL    HostOsCheck
[c01][FAIL][HostOsCheck] Percentage working c01 FAIL    HostOsCheck
[c02][OK][ILOStatusCheck] Percentage of working c02 OK  ILOStatusCheck
```

The string can have any log message in it, but if it passes then the status is in [] with either [OK] or [FAIL]. Also the name of the Check is in []

I know I can try regex and use col.str. so trying below:

```
df['name'] = msg.str.extract(r'([\w{1,}Check])', expand = True)
```

but I get below instead of the full Check name HostOsCheck etc

```
    0
0   f
1   f
2   S
3   f
4   f
```

same for status:

```
df['status'] = msg.str.extract(r'([OK|FAIL])', expand = True)

    0
0   O
1   O
2   O
3   O
4   O
```

EDIT:

Figured out. Was missing the \ for [] as it was taking

```
msg.str.extract(r'\[(\w{1,}Check)\]', expand = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

### considering a.txt contains the logs..
a.txt

```
[c01][OK][HostOsCheck] Skip cji02  because it is DOWN
[c01][Stage 3] 2/3 checks passed
[c01][FAIL][HostOsCheck] Percentage working
[c01][FAIL][HostOsCheck] Percentage working
[c02][OK][ILOStatusCheck] Percentage of working
```

python code

```
import pandas as pd
b=[]
with open('a.txt','r') as f:
    while 1:
        s=f.readlines()
        for i in s:
            a=i.split("]")
            b.append([x.replace("[","") for x in a])
        break
df=pd.DataFrame(b,columns=['Col','Status','Name','Reason'])
print(df)
```

Comment: status is not a col. I want to create it by extracting

Comment: thats not what it is. Its a data frame with a col for log. I want to extract specific values as new cols from it. Check my update what I am trying to do